# Unique value for same fragment class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

In my project I'm dynamically adding same fragment class on top of another using:

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.pull, SwipeFragment::class.java, null)
                .addToBackStack(null) 
                .commit()
```

Is there any value that differentiates instances of those fragments? The fragment id is the same for every instance and for the use case I need to use **add** method.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can just construct a new ``Fragment`` and ``add`` it, you're not using IDs here. You can add a tag (which is ``null` in your example) if you want to find that specific fragment later - just make it something unique!

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing this problem because you created the fragment object as Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use their hashcode to differentiate between the instances